# Generating html from array of objects

Tags: angular

I'm trying to generate html tags from the below object response,

```
"view": [{
  "type": 'text',
  "depth": 0,
  "text": "This is a sample text"
}]
```

What I wanted to achieve here is, I wanted to loop thought each `type` & append the appropriate html tags.

```
<h1>This is a sample heading</h1>
<p>This is a sample text<p>
```

I'm looking something like this,

```
  private generateHtml (content) {
    let contentString = [];

    switch(type) {
      case 'text': return `<p>${contentString.join('')}</p>`;
  }
```

Looking for a scoffing holding code, to start with my project

Note:- Above code is not functional, its just for an idea on what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you should go with your idea, seems perfact!

Comment: I looking for some scoffing holding code, So that I can build on top of it

Comment: I think you need to iterate over each element in the array and get output via this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach as it will be better to not use functions directly from html as it will overload web browser memory.
So you need to refactor some data.

> Raw content

```
   content = {
    "data": {
      "areas": [{
        "sections": [{
          "rjf": [
            {
              "type": "heading-1",
              "depth": 0,
              "text": "This is a sample heading"
            },
            {
              "type": "paragraph",
              "depth": 1,
              "text": "This a sample text /n"
            },
          ]
        }]
      }]
    }
  };
```

> Additional Functions

```
    constructor() {
    this.content.data.areas.forEach((val)=>{
        val.sections.forEach((elem)=>{
          elem.rjf.forEach(async (data)=>{
            data['generatedHtml'] = await this.generateHtml(data);
          });
        });
    });
  }

  private generateHtml (elem: any): string {
    switch(elem.type) {
      case 'heading-1': return `<h1>${elem.text.trim()}</h1>`;
      case 'paragraph': return `<p>${elem.text.trim()}</p>`;
    }
  }
```

Also you need to use regex for convert any `\n` to `<br>`.

Here is [ONLINE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5zeah) of this.
let me know if it's work for you. Happy Coding... :D

EDITED:

> Here is the HTML code

```
<div *ngFor="let cont of content?.data?.areas">
  <div *ngFor="let section of cont?.sections">
    <div *ngFor="let data of section?.rjf">
      <span [innerHTML]="data.generatedHtml"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. :-). Also is der any better way to filter type instead of using multiple forEach loop ?

Comment: It's your way of achieving the code loop. See how you can took better approach with JSON data for less looping.